# Adding items to a global list in TFS via the SDK

Tags: .net, tfs-sdk

I wish to add or list items from a global list in TFS 2010 via the TFS SDK.

I have discovered the following methods:

- `XmlDocument WorkItemStore.ExportGlobalLists()`
- `void WorkItemStore.ImportGlobalLists(XmlElement listsElement);`
- `void WorkItemStore.ImportGlobalLists(string lists);`

Which appear to export/import all the global lists as a single XML document.

Is there any way to just update a single global list (i.e. adding/removing an individual item) as opposed to fetching or replacing the entire set of global lists.

Also, is there anywhere within the TFS user interface that individual user can make changes to a global list - or is this not something a user is expected to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is currently no way to add a single item to a global list. You need to Export the entire list, make you changes and then import that list back into TFS.
2. See Edwalds post for a UI to edit the Global lists

Comment: I didn't notice it at first, so I think you should emphasize that the `ImportGlobalLists` methods actually *can* be used to modify a single global *list*. You're correct that you can't add a single item, but the OP seems to think that those methods don't even allow a single *list* to be updated (i.e. that *all lists* have to be updated).

Answer (score 3):

The TFS Power Tools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da) have a global list editor.

You can start it from the Tools menu

[image]

[image]